# How to get change points in oracle select query?

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min, row-number

How can I select change points from this data set

```
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   100
5   100
6   100
7   100
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  100
12  100
13  0
14  0
15  0
```

I want this result

```
4  7  100 
11 12 100
```

Comment: personally, i would do this with plsql, create a cursor ordered by col1, store the value of col2, compare the value of col2 with the stored value for each pass through the loop. You can then store the col1 value when there is a change. But if you want this in SQL, someone else may be able to help.

Comment: Why not `1 3 0`, `8 10 0`, and `13 15 0`?

Comment: @davegreen100 *Never* do in **PL/SQL** when you could do the same in pure **SQL**.

Comment: @Lalit, unless you want the code to be repeated as part of a batch process. I lean towards PL/SQL on this one purely as i don't know how to do it in SQL

Comment: @davegreen100 Well, if you know how to use analytic and aggregate functions, then it is a simple SQL. See my answer.

Comment: @BobJarvis Seems like data needs to filtered on column B where value is zero. Then it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - the question in my comment was intended to give OP a chance to explain the problem more clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query based on analytic functions `lag()` and `lead()` gives expected output:

```
select id, nid, point 
  from (
    select id, point, p1, lead(id) over (order by id) nid 
      from (
        select id, point,
            decode(lag(point) over (order by id), point, 0, 1) p1,
            decode(lead(point) over (order by id), point, 0, 2) p2
         from test)
     where p1<>0 or p2<>0)
 where p1=1 and point<>0
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59418/1)</sup>

---

Edit: You may want to change line 3 in case there only one row for *changing point*:

```
    ...
    select id, point, p1,
        case when p1=1 and p2=2 then id else lead(id) over (order by id) end nid 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be simple to use **ROW_NUMBER** analytic function, **MIN** and **MAX**.

This is a frequently asked question about finding the interval/series of values and skip the gaps. I like the word given to it as [Tabibitosan method](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1007478?tstart=0) by Aketi Jyuuzou.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT MIN(A),
  2    MAX(A),
  3    b
  4  FROM
  5    ( SELECT a,b, a-Row_Number() over(order by a) AS rn FROM t WHERE b <> 0
  6    )
  7  GROUP BY rn,
  8    b
  9  ORDER BY MIN(a);

    MIN(A)     MAX(A)          B
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          7        100
        11         12        100

SQL>
```